# Native module cannot be null - device info

Tags: react-native

I get an error after importing react-native-device-info. Can you help me for this error?
I'm using xcode simulator

```
import * as React from 'react'; 
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'; 
import DrawerNavigator from './navigation/DrawerNavigator';
 
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info' 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you provide which type of error you are getting

Comment: iOS Bundling complete 317ms
Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
iOS Running app on iPhone SE (3rd generation)
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

-----

Native module cannot be null.

Comment: import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info' ;

when i remove it everything works fine

Comment: do one thing delete node_modules and clear cache and restart server and emulator reinstall device-info library and link it

Answer (score 0):

first uninstall **device-info** library and delete node_modules and clear cache

```
rm -rf node_modules/ 
npm cache clean --force
npm install 
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

and reinstall **device-info**

```
npm i react-native-device-info
```

then link it

```
npm link react-native-device-info
```